# unable to delete msg when reaches to the destination in omnet++?

Tags: c++, broadcast, omnet++

I'm a newbie in OMNeT++ and I want to make a simple broadcast mechanism where starting node sends a msg and it will broadcast it to all nodes connecting in a mesh topology. When msg reaches its destination, the msg will be deleted and does not broadcast further more. Continuously, I'm working on it from 2 days by following it's official documentation. My code is successfully simulated. But it  doesn't delete the msg when it reaches to destination. I'm starting with just 25 nodes (computer) in which source node is computer0 and destination node is computer24. Tell me, where I'm wrong. Below is my source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>

using namespace omnetpp;

class computer : public cSimpleModule
{
protected:
    virtual void forwardMessage(cMessage *msg);
    virtual void initialize() override;
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
};

Define_Module(computer);

void computer::initialize()
{
    if (getIndex() == 0) {

        char msgname[20];
        sprintf(msgname, "msg-%d", getIndex());
        cMessage *msg = new cMessage(msgname);
        scheduleAt(0.0, msg);
    }
}

void computer::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    if (getIndex() == 24) {

            EV << "Message " << msg << " arrived.\n";
            delete msg;
        }
        else {

            forwardMessage(msg);
        }
    }

void computer::forwardMessage(cMessage *msg)
{

    int n = gateSize("gate");
    int k = intuniform(0, n-1);

    EV << "Forwarding message " << msg << " on gate[" << k << "]\n";
    send(msg, "gate$o", k);
}
```

simulation snap: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4JRQ.png

Comment: Could you paste the picture into your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `getIndex()` method that return the position of a module in the array of modules. However, the simulation snap shows that you do not use array of modules. Therefore `getIndex()` returns zero for every module.

The simplest way to correct your model is to check the name of a module instead of its position, for example:

```
void computer::initialize()
{
   // if (getIndex() == 0) {
   if (isName("computer0")) {
        char msgname[20];
   // ...


void computer::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
   // if (getIndex() == 24) {
   if (isName("computer24")) {
        EV << "Message " << msg << " arrived.\n";
   // ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.